# In HDLC, how to recognize bit stuffing?

Tags: protocols, frame, bitstuffing

In framing for the HDLC protocol, assume the receiver receives the following string of bits:

[…] 011111010 […]

How can it realize whether the sequence “011111010” is real data, or the result of a bit stuffing operation from an original flag-like sequence “01111110”?

how can the receiver recognize the two different options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply. There are no two options. The sequence `01111110 (0x7E)` is not allowed for the original data in the frame, i.e. it is reserved for the flags. So, while **bit-stuffing**, only *data* bit sequences are affected, but not *flag* bit sequences. Such any sequence the receiver sees with 5 ones in a row is definitely not a flag sequence, which has kept its successive 6 ones.

> Noting that the flag character has the bit pattern 01111110 (a contiguous sequence of six 1 bits), bit stuffing arranges for a 0 bit to be inserted after any contiguous string of five 1 bits appearing **in a place other than the flag character itself**.

-- (reference see below)

Note that *any* data bit sequence of pattern [x zeroes] [5 ones] [y zeroes] is stuffed to [x zeroes] [5 ones] [***y+1 zeroes***]. So you will receive e.g. a data sequence of `01111101` as `011111001`, one of `011111001` as `0111110001`and so on. The receiver knows that this happens on sender-side and removes any additional zero after 5 ones at unstuffing.

And when **byte-stuffing** any `0x7E` found in the *data* is replaced by the 2-byte `0x7D5E`, whereby `0x7D` serves as an escape character, before being put into the frame. Again, the flag sequences remain untouched.

See [K.R.Fall & W.R.Stevens (2012), *TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1: The Protocols*, 2nd Ed., Addison-Wesley, pp.131](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tcpip-illustrated-volume/9780132808200/) for the whole procedure:

> The PPP frame format, in the common case when HDLC-like framing is used [...], is surrounded by two 1-byte Flag fields containing the fixed value 0x7E. These fields are used by the two stations on the ends of the point-to-point link for finding the beginning and end of the frame. A small problem arises if the value 0x7E itself occurs inside the frame. This is handled in one of two ways, depending on whether PPP is operating over an asynchronous or a synchronous link. For asynchronous links, PPP uses character stuffing (also called byte stuffing). If the flag character appears elsewhere in the frame, it is replaced with the 2-byte sequence 0x7D5E (0x7D is known as the “PPP escape character”). If the escape character itself appears in the frame, it is replaced with the 2-byte sequence 0x7D5D. Thus, the receiver replaces 0x7D5E with 0x7E and 0x7D5D with 0x7D upon receipt. On synchronous links (e.g., T1 lines, T3 lines), PPP uses bit stuffing. Noting that the flag character has the bit pattern 01111110 (a contiguous sequence of six 1 bits), bit stuffing arranges for a 0 bit to be inserted after any contiguous string of five 1 bits appearing in a place other than the flag character itself. Doing so implies that bytes may be sent as more than 8 bits, but this is generally OK, as low layers of the serial processing hardware are able to “unstuff” the bit stream, restoring it to its prestuffed pattern.

Comment: Actually, after receiving sequence "011111010," the receiver may think that the intermediate 0 is the result of bit-stuffing, so it reverts sequence "01111110" which is NOT interpreted as a flag but as real data. My question is: what if "011111010" is already my real data? How should I force the receiver not to "remove" the intermediate 0?

Comment: You wouldn't receive 011111010 but 0111110010 -- with an extra null. And if 0111110010 was your real data, you would have received 01111100010. And so on. It's just as simple as this, but I admit I had to struggle with this, too, when I once encountered that topic.

Comment: Any data bit sequence of pattern <x zeroes><5 ones><x zeroes> is stuffed to <x zeroes><5 ones><**x+1** zeroes>. The additional zero is removed at unstuffing.

Comment: Edited my answer correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now, but still not fully convincing to me, sorry ;) So, according to your answer, if I want to transmit "011111010" I should send "0111110010" with an extra null. So the receiver removes the extra null and comes back with the original sequence "011111010." Does it mean that the receiver can only remove ONE NULL? Meaning, from "011111010," can it also remove the other null, and get the sequence "01111110"?

Comment: Remember -- sender and receiver use the same protocol, i.e. a *defined* set of rules that determines how data is transmitted. The receiver removes only one zero, because only one zero was put in according to the HDCL protocol. He doesn't remove two zeroes as this was not defined in this protocol. If he would, than his implementation of HDCL would be faulty and would need a very very urgent patch.

Comment: You are Italian, I am German. We both use English based on the same rules (vocabulary, grammar etc) defined for the English language and learned in school. If you send a message in English (= putting in one zero) and at reception I apply the rules of French, (= removing two zeroes), then we would have a heavy communication problem based on my very faulty implementation of English :-D

Comment: And why do you have the right to expect me to use English (= use HDLC)? Because it's defined in the SO rules (= predefined or negotiated net protocol). If I start to talk to you in French or whatever, my post and comments will be removed by the mods (= discarded as erroneous). I'll have to repost my messages in proper English (= retransmit).

Comment: I see, all clear  thanks!